# ReactJS problem with defaulting value on select tag

Tags: html, reactjs

Trying to set the default value on a select tag in a react component but I cannot get it to work:

```
const ComboBox = (props) => {
  const options = [
    { id: 1, value: "SHOES" },
    { id: 2, value: "SOCKS" },
    { id: 3, value: "SHIRTS" },
    { id: 4, value: "BELTS" }
  ];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
      <select id={props.id} value={props.selected} onChange={props.changeHandler}>
        {options.map((row, ndx) => (
          <option key={ndx} value={row.id}>{row.value}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Always selects the first option in the list.

Provided an example of the behavior here:  [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-liskov-o8q9l?file=/src/App.js:65-663)

Comment: I know it doesn't make a difference but it would be best practice to use option.id instead of index as key. https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls replace below code. use value={props.value} not props.selected

```
<select
        id={props.id}
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.changeHandler}
      >
        {options.map((row, ndx) => (
          <option key={ndx} disable={ndx === 0 ? "true" : false} value={row.id}>
            {row.value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Maybe add an explanation and a Code Sandbox?

Comment: data passed in value props from parent component not in selected props. He just missed the correct props name

Comment: I did misname the prop and fixing that corrects the problem in code sandbox where the  options are a constant.  Trying to use a fetch to populate the data from a server call does not work; however.  Should I post it as a separate question?

Comment: Better if you put the actual code with useEffect. So we can understand better and solve the exact scenario.

Comment: I actually just figured out what the problem is.  In my `changeHandler` - I am upper-casing the id's; therefore they do not match the option id's in my select.  Thanks for all your help folks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set default value to 1 then you can do it using usestate in react.
here is the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ComboBox = (props) => {
  const options = [
    { id: 1, value: "SHOES" },
    { id: 2, value: "SOCKS" },
    { id: 3, value: "SHIRTS" },
    { id: 4, value: "BELTS" }
  ];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
      <select id={props.id} value={props.value} onChange={props.changeHandler}>
        {options.map((row, ndx) => (
          <option key={ndx} value={row.id}>
            {row.value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(1);
  const comboHandler = (e) => setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComboBox
        id="test"
        name="test"
        value={selectedValue}
        changeHandler={comboHandler}
      ></ComboBox>
      <div>
        <h2>Value Should Be {selectedValue}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Just note the default usestate value is the first one

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(1);
```

You can change the value inside useState(here) to make the default selected value.